# Escaping the '[' bracket in a JSON string without there being another ']'

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I am trying to map a custom shortcut to VS code that will paste the following string (which clears the console), using the multi_command tool:

```
"command": "multiCommand.clearConsole",
    "sequence": [
        {
            "command": "type",
            "args": {
              "text": "print("\\033\[2J)
            }
          }
    ]
```

I have used a double backslash to escape the first backslash, but I need a way of escaping the '[' open bracket.

Does anyone know if it's possible? or an easier way to do it? I just want to clear the console which is hosted on an external device (interacting via PyCOM Console) and interacts via python command line.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double-quote and the backslash before `[`, the bracket is a valid JSON character:

```
{
    "command": "multiCommand.clearConsole",
    "sequence": [{
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
            "text": "print(\"\\033\\[2J)"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested and the JSON file was happy with it, but it then prints: 
**("\033\ [2J]")** with an extra "\" and "]" character...

Maybe its something weird to do with VS code

Comment: Isn't **"\033[2J]"** what you wanted to use according to your question ? I have no idea what you are trying to do, just fixed your JSON :)

Answer (score 1):

This keybinding - chose whatever keybinding you want - will clear the console:

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+z",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "clear\u000d" }
  }
```

or you could use that `"text"` in your macro.

Focus in editor.

Comment: I tried pasting this into my 'keybindings.json' file but when I press the corresponding keybinding nothing happens

Comment: Which terminal shell are you using?  I know it works in powershell and bash at least.